clangformat under visual studio
I would like to use clang-format.exe directly from the command line on a system where visual studio is installed and can't find the location to the application. Where can we find it relative to the VS installation root?

For future reference, Windows Explorer has search functionality.

Regarding the path of clang-format.exe in VS, the default path is: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin. Please make sure that you have installed the Desktop development with C++ workload.

I have the professional version, but that boils down to the same path. Awesome! Thank you
